# Is there a difference in putting your SQL query in a variable first rather than in the prepare?

Tags: php

Is there any difference between the following code, be it speed wise or is it just  preference?

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=?";
$user = $database->prepare($sql);
$user->execute(array(Request::post('username')));
```

**VS**

```
$user = $database->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=?");
$user->execute(array(Request::post('username')));
```

I have not tried benchmarking, so the only visual difference is less amount of code, why should I do one rather than the other, or should I do both?

Comment: I doubt there's a noticeable difference, this seems like a matter of personal preference. Rule of thumb though; be consistent. Pick one style and stick with it.

Comment: In your example they're equivalent. The only time you'd really care about this is when you re-use the same query, in which case you'd want to use a variable so anytime you need to change the query you'd only have to change it once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=?";
$user = $database->prepare($sql);
$user->execute(array(Request::post('username')));
```

VS

```
$user = $database->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=?");
$user->execute(array(Request::post('username')));
```

If you are using the select statement only once, then don't put it in a variable, to lessen the memory and the process used in creating that variable and storing its value.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=?";
```

If you are using it more than once, then you can use variables to avoid repetitive initializations

e.g instead of creating many `SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=?` instances
you can just store it in a variable for a shorter and more modular code

There are also other things to consider like variable scope, etc...

There is a tiny difference ("The first one consumes more memory because you stored the string in a variable") but it would be very minimal and won't be noticeable at all.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is NO. There is not difference.

For more complex queries, you might want to use option 1 just for better understanding (better reading) of the query.

Second option, have to load the sql query in variable, but it is minimal the difference (space and performance)

Comment: What you want to say different than @j08691

Comment: @siddhesh if you checked the time between my answer and j08691 comment, it is only 3 min. When I started writing my answer there was no comment. Thanks for the down vote for being slow. I guess next time I will write faster.

Answer (score 0):

**Performance-wise**, there is basically no difference.

Performance is not all, though. I personally favor the first version because I feel it is **more maintainable** (lines of code are shorter, even if their number is greater), **easier to read**, and it is **easier to access** the query in case something goes wrong:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=?';
try {
    $user = $database->prepare($sql);
    $user->execute(array(Request::post('username')));
} catch (\PDOException $e) {
    throw new MyQueryException(array( 'query' => $sql , ... ));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you'll reuse this query - you should store it. In this case you don't duplicate your code. Thats all. In general similar micro-optimizations doesn't sounds good. Better write more understandable code, but not poorly optimized.